# What does $\overset \times =$ mean?

Tags: notation

I came across this symbol on page xix of the book *Universal Artificial Intelligence* by Hutter:

> [image]

([link to full text of book](http://sanghv.com/download/Soft/Machine%20Learning,%20Artificial%20Intelligence,%20Mathematics%20eBooks/AI/universal%20artificial%20intelligence%20(2005).pdf))

It is used for the Solomonoff-Levin universal semi-measure.  I've never seen it before, and wondering if anyone can help me understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Can't find it in the unicode set of mathematical symbols (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is specified on that very same page:

> [image]

Thus, $a\overset{\times}{=}b$ means "equal, within a multiplicative constant".

More information is on p.33:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you Zev. I wish I had seen that before posting the question.

Comment: Would that be $a=c \cdot b$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I've updated my answer. In particular, $a$ and $b$ are intended to be functions, not constants, so $a\overset{\times}{=}b$ means $a=O(b)$ and $b=O(a)$.

Comment: $a = \Theta(b)$ is the more usual notation for what's described here as $a\overset{\times}{=}b$ (at least, for $a$ and $b$ positive, etc.)